# How can I display my results in this specific format?

Tags: c++

I have a homework question. I need help displaying my results in this format:

```
Price1      Price2      Price3
Price4      Price5      Price6
Price7      Price8      Price9
```

How can I display the results in the desired format in a `cout` statement? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     // use a constant Declaration
     const int SIZE = 9;

    // use a variable Declaration
    float prices[SIZE];

   cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
   // prompt user to enter all 9 values :
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
    cout << "Enter the value: " << i + 1 << "-> ";
    cin >> prices[i];
   }

   cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
   // Display all values in the array
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
    cout << "value Entered " << i + 1 << "\t\t " << right << setw(7) << prices[i] << endl;
   }
}
```

This is the output when running the code:

```
Enter the value: 1-> 21
Enter the value: 2-> 34
Enter the value: 3-> 54
Enter the value: 4-> 12
Enter the value: 5-> 65
Enter the value: 6-> 34
Enter the value: 7-> 76
Enter the value: 8-> 88
Enter the value: 9-> 90

----------------------------------------------------
value Entered 1            21.00
value Entered 2            34.00
value Entered 3            54.00
value Entered 4            12.00
value Entered 5            65.00
value Entered 6            34.00
value Entered 7            76.00
value Entered 8            88.00
value Entered 9            90.00

--------------------------------
Process exited after 16.86 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You can use nested loops for the output. The outer loop iterates over the rows and the inner loop iterates over the columns. It's unclear for me how you want to handle the string `"value Entered"`. The comment says `// prompt user to enter all 10 values :` but your array has only 9 elements.

Comment: Alternatively you can check if `i % 3 == 2` in the output loop and only then print a linebreak.

Comment: You only want a newline every 3 items.  Your current output statement outputs a newline for every item.

Comment: Thanks. Now it seems that your desired output was just a description. (there's no "Value entered" string e.g.) Please show the desired output for this specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // use a constant Declaration
   const int SIZE = 9;

   // use a variable Declaration
   float prices[SIZE];

   // prompt user to enter all 10 values :
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter the value: " << i + 1 << "-> ";
      cin >> prices[i];
   }

   cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
   // Display all values in the array
   int index = 0;

   while (index < SIZE)
   {
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ++ctr)
      {
         cout << "values Entered " << index + 1 << " " << prices[index] << "\t\t";
         ++index;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions